# Rake is in my Gem path and yet Bundler can not find it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler

Bundler can not find Rake.

How do I fix my Gem path so that my Ruby gems get installed in a place where Bundler can find it?

If I do:

```
  gem env
```

I see:

```
  RubyGems Environment:
    - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
    - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 645) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
      - ruby
      - universal-darwin-15
    - GEM PATHS:
       - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
       - /Users/lkrubner/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
       - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
    - GEM CONFIGURATION:
       - :update_sources => true
       - :verbose => true
       - :backtrace => false
       - :bulk_threshold => 1000
       - "install" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
       - "update" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
    - REMOTE SOURCES:
       - https://rubygems.org/
```

And Rake is there:

```
   ls -al /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems 

   rake-0.9.6
   rake-10.4.2
   rake-11.2.2
   rdoc-4.0.0
   test-unit-2.0.0.0
```

But none of this matters for the current project.

I am taking over a Rails project from another developer.

Rails 4.2

Rake 11..2.2

Ruby 2.0.0

If I look in

```
  .bundler/config
```

I see:

```
  BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/cache
  BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

If I use "find" I can see that I've installed several versions of Rake:

```
  vendor/cache/rake-11.2.2.gem
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-11.2.2
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2
```

But most of these are going to a ruby 2.1 folder, instead of 2.0.

But if I try:

```
  bundle exec rake db:setup
```

I get:

```
  Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources
```

I've tried "bundle install".

I've tried deleting Gemfile.lock.

I've tried to avoid using "bundle exec".

I can't get anything to work.

I just need to get the system to use one path. The versions are not very important.

How do I get everything to agree on one path?

If I run "bundle install" then in the output I see "Using rake 11.2.2". So the "bundle" command sees rake when Bundler is doing the "install" task, but not when it is doing the "exec" task.

By the way:

```
  which rake
  /usr/local/bin/rake
```

This is hard-coded to the 2.0 version of Ruby:

```
  #!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  #
  # This file was generated by RubyGems.
  #
  # The application 'rake' is installed as part of a gem, and
  # this file is here to facilitate running it.
  #

  require 'rubygems'

  version = ">= 0"

  if ARGV.first
    str = ARGV.first
    str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
    if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
      version = $1
      ARGV.shift
    end
  end

  gem 'rake', version
  load Gem.bin_path('rake', 'rake', version)
```

[[  UPDATE ]]

[[  UPDATE ]]

I deleted:

.bashrc

.bash_profile

.zshrc

and I ran:

```
   chsh -s /bin/bash
```

I am on a Mac. This should have changed my shell from zsh to bash.

I then started over in a terminal window, to be sure all changes were loaded.

Now, if I run "bundle install" the gems seem to install into vendor/cache/ but I get this error:

```
  Installing paperclip 5.0.0
  Gem::InstallError: paperclip requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
```

So I run:

```
  rbenv install 2.1.0
```

and I run "bundle install" again, and I get the same error.

The ruby version is:

```
  ruby -v
  ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Any advice?

If I run:

```
  gem env
```

I see:

```
 - GEM PATHS:
   - /Users/lkrubner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
   - /Users/lkrubner/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
```

Comment: Is `gem 'rake'` included of your `Gemfile`?

Comment: try `bundle exec gem list | grep rake` and see if you have more than one version installed and what order the versions are listed. Then you use `gem uninstall rake` and pick the version(s) you want to remove until you only have the correct one in play.

Comment: @Holger -- I've tried it 3 ways: without 'rake' in the Gemfile, with it in the Gemfile but without a specified version, and with it and also with a version specified. Nothing works.

Comment: @jaydel -- if I run "bundle exec gem list" I simply get the error message: "Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources"

Comment: If I run "bundle install" then in the output I see "Using rake 11.2.2". So the "bundle" command sees rake when Bundler is doing the "install" task, but not when it is doing the "exec" task.

Comment: can you remove `BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'` from .bundler/config
 and try

Comment: @Nikhil -- I think that problem was solved. I'm dealing with a new problem now. I mention it in the update. Maybe I should start a new question? The problem now is that "gem" and "bundle" and rbenv all seem to use different paths.

Comment: This is the problem I have now: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1127

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is fixed now. Deleting all of .bashrc and .bash_profile and .zshrc and changing the default shell back to bash and deleting all mentions of rvm and reinstalling rbenv and reinstalling "gem" and then "Bundler" seemed to fix at least some of the problems with paths. And I fixed the issue with Paperclip by doing "gem install paperclip" which I guess installed paperclip globally, but at least it works on my local Mac. Very fragile, but things are working.

I wish I could use Clojure for this project. Every time I tangle with Ruby I end up wrestling with this endless maze of path problems. With Clojure, I am protected by Leiningen, which seems to figure this stuff out with pure magic.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `gem update bundler` to fix this issue.